# Get error code of FacebookOauthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my application I want to log all the error messages along with its error code when FacebookOauthException occurs.but I couldn't find way to do so. 
According to the facebook the exception object contains

```
     {
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix 
                time SOME_TIME. The current unix time is SOME_TIME.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 190
    "error_subcode": 463
}
```

and in c# I am trying to catch exception in the following way :

```
            try
            {
                FacebookWebClient facebookWebClient = new FacebookWebClient(pAccessToken);
                JsonObject facebookPagesJsonObj = facebookWebClient.Get(@"\me\accounts") as JsonObject;
                JsonArray faceookPagesJsonArray = facebookPagesJsonObj["data"] as JsonArray;
           }

        catch (FacebookApiException facebookException)
        {

            if (facebookException.ErrorType.ToLower().Equals("oauthexception"))
        {
             //want to access error code,error message and error_subcode here.
        }
        }
```

It would be great if anyone can help me.
Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using PHP, but maybe the exception object is set up the same way. If you include a link to C# SDK docs, that could help too.

In PHP, the Facebook exception has the getResult() method, which returns an 'error' hash with keys 'message', 'type' and 'code'.

So to use:

```
$res = facebookException->getResult();
$error = $res['error'];
// Now use: $error['code'], $error['type'], $error['message']
```